# Push Notifications with TaskManager, react-native expo

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications

im trying to run a function when the app is in background and the user receives a notification, but doesnt interact with it, to do this im using task manager, since sdk 42 its possible to run a function in background, having this code:

```
  const BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK = 'remote-notification';

  TaskManager.defineTask(BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK, () => {
    BackgroundTimer.runBackgroundTimer(() => { 
      console.log("holalahola");
      // schedulePushNotification();
    }, 
    2000);
  });

  Notifications.registerTaskAsync(BACKGROUND_NOTIFICATION_TASK);
```

this works on android, cause when app is in background and i send a notification the code in the task will executes, but in ios it doesnt, already added in app.json `remote-notification`

```
 "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "infoPlist": {
        "UIBackgroundModes": [
          "remote-notification"
        ]
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.xxxx"
    }
```

is there a way i can run a function on background or a way to detect background event? using managed workflow and expo, was thinking if its not possible, then in the background just will be fetching every 15min if something happened

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [this github thread](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/13767#issuecomment-1373174797), basically you need to include `_contentAvailable: true` in your notification payload to expo push notification's service:

> Example payload for ios
>
> ```
> { to: <push_token>, "_contentAvailable": true}
> ```